# Limit string chars - PHP

Tags: php, string, rss, limit, feed

I am building an RSS script with mysql, and i dont want an extra field in the database... i want to shrink down the body of the article with a "... Read More" but im not sure how i can limit the number of chars echoed out onto the page?

Of course not this syntax, but something along the lines of:

```
echo(limit($row['newsBody'], 1000));
```

I dont mind if it takes 15 lines of code to do this ;)

P.S. I am sure limit() is a function, please dont tell me .. its just an example ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can achieve this easily using strlen() and substr().

Comment: Plus, to avoid cutting words, wordwrap(): http://de3.php.net/wordwrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo(substr($row['newsBody'], 0, 1000));
```

The [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function is what you are looking for. Or you can use [`mb_substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) if you are dealing with multi-byte strings.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
$body = $row['newsBody'];
$length = strlen($body) > 1000 ? 1000 : strlen($1000);
echo substr($body,0, $length);
```

It'll print the first 1000 characters or the whole message which ever is shorter

Comment: +1 for the fall-back *or whichever is shorter* consideration.

Comment: The `strlen()` check is not necessary as `substr($s, 0, $length)` returns at most `$length` chars depending on the length of `$s`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Ah yes, true. :)

I'll just leave it here since it might give someone the idea to do checks like this in other cases where it may matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
substr( $string, 0, 1000 );
```